# Does this trigonometry series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin3n}{1+3^n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is there any tests or method by which I could test the convergence of the following series:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin3n}{1+3^n}$$

Comment: Have you tried upper bound and lower bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
0<\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(3n)}{1+3^n}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(3n)}{1+3^n}\right|< \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{3^n}=\frac12
$$

Comment: Thanks, did not thought of it

Comment: @user332127 You are welcome.

Comment: one question, why is $|\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin3n}{1+3^n}|$ < $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+3^n}$

Comment: @user332127 Because you always have $|\sin(3n)|\leq1$ and you have $\frac{1}{1+3^n}<\frac1{3^n}.$

Comment: To prove convergence, do not compute absolute value of the sum.  Instead compute sum of the absolute values to get absolute convergence.  So begin your calculation with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(3n)}{1+3^n}\right|$

Comment: @GEdgar Why the absolute convergence of a series is sufficient?

Comment: See "absolute convergence" in your textbook.

Comment: OK, thank you for this lesson.